# Lexicographic comparison in Rust

Tags: rust

I am trying to find the smallest lexicographic string in a vector of strings in rust (rust equivalent of python `min(strings)`). However, I am not sure how I would be able to compare strings lexicographically with rust in the first place. How would I go about doing so?

It seems like comparison with the `<` or `>` works, but I am not sure if that is actually true lexicographic comparison.

Comment: As for "How would I go about doing so?", step one would be checking the [official docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html), particularly the implementation of [`Ord`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#impl-Ord) for `str`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`impl Ord for str`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#impl-Ord)

> Strings are ordered lexicographically by their byte values. This orders Unicode code points based on their positions in the code charts. This is not necessarily the same as “alphabetical” order, which varies by language and locale. Sorting strings according to culturally-accepted standards requires locale-specific data that is outside the scope of the `str` type.

Comment: Thanks! Are strings represented by a u8/vec also ordered lexicographically?

Comment: @Andrew [Why not check yourself](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#impl-Ord)? :)

Comment: Thanks. I'm very sorry that I am not very good at doc-fu as you are.